# Unable to parse Json in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

Here I tried to parse the data from my local server but unable to parse it and it returning empty data and below are my model classes from which the data I was passing to an table view which can anyone help me what's wrong in implementing it?

Here I had attached my image which follows the Json format:
[image]

Code:

```
 var homePageModel = [HomeBanner]()

 func HomeBannerDownloadJsonWithURL(){
        let url = URL(string: homePageUrl)!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil { print(error!); return }
            do {
                if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]] {
                    for item in jsonObj {
                        print(item)
                        for dict in item {
                            print(dict)
                            let dict = HomeBanner(json: item)
                            self.homePageModel.append(dict!)
                            print(self.homePageModel)
                        }
                    }
                    print(self.homePageModel)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.homeTableView.delegate = self
                        self.homeTableView.dataSource = self
                        self.homeTableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
     }
     struct HomeBanner {

    let title : String?
    let titleInArabic : String?
    let showTitle : String?
    var banner = [ChildrenBanners]()

    init?(json : [String:Any]) {
        if let customAttribute = json["childran_banners"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                var result = [ChildrenBanners]()
                for obj in customAttribute {
                    result.append(ChildrenBanners(json: obj as! [String : String])!)
                }
                self.banner = result
                } else {
                    self.banner = [ChildrenBanners]()
                }
        self.title = json["title"] as? String ?? ""
        print(self.title)
        self.titleInArabic = json["title_in_arabic"] as? String ?? ""
        self.showTitle = json["show_title"] as? String ?? ""
    }
 }

 struct ChildrenBanners {

    let bannerId : String?
    let name : String?
    let status : String?
    let sliderId : String?
    let desktopImage : String?
    let mobileImage : String?
    let imageAlt : String?
    let sortOrder : String?
    let startTime : String?
    let endTime : String?

     init?(json : [String:Any]) {

        self.bannerId = json["banner_id"] as? String ?? ""
        print(self.bannerId)
        self.name = json["name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.status = json["status"] as? String ?? ""
        self.sliderId = json["slider_id"] as? String ?? ""
        self.desktopImage = json["desktop_image"] as? String ?? ""
        self.mobileImage = json["mobile_image"] as? String ?? ""
        self.imageAlt = json["image_alt"] as? String ?? ""
        self.sortOrder = json["sort_order"] as? String ?? ""
        self.startTime = json["start_time"] as? String ?? ""
        self.endTime = json["end_time"] as? String ?? ""

    }

}
```

Comment: Post the actual JSON, not an image.

Comment: My Json is local server url in which if I post also you can't access @ryantxr

Comment: what result are you getting in this jsonObj ?

Comment: I am getting my Json array data shown in image @ShauketSheikh

Comment: Please paste that data in quest , you attached image. i need to test it in my side.

Answer (score 0):

Root of json is an array and then second level is dictionary with keys `list1`, `list2` etc. You are missing that in your code. Should be something like this (I haven't compiled it).

```
if let data = data, let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String:[String:Any]]] {
    for item in jsonObj {
        for (_, dict) in item {
            if let obj = HomeBanner(json: dict) {
                self.homePageModel.append(obj)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

There are lot of other issues in your code. Like force unwrapping optional. Using same parameters again within a scope. For example.

```
for dict in item {                            
    let dict = HomeBanner(json: item)
    // ....
}
```

You shouldn't use same param names like you are using `dict` it hides the scope of the outer `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

Just try these lines of code

```
            if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]] {
              self.homePageModel = jsonObj.map{HomeBanner(json: $0)}


              print(self.homePageModel)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.homeTableView.delegate = self
                    self.homeTableView.dataSource = self
                    self.homeTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

and there is no necessity of making optional initializer for `HomeBanner` and `ChildrenBanners` just use  `init(json : [String : Any]){}` for both struct